# Change BG color of DATATABLE

Tags: r, datatable

I want to change the color of background cell of the first and last row of this Datatable.
How can i specify this in format_style() function?

```
df <- data.frame(categoria = c("A","B","C","D"),
                 posição = c(4,3,2,1))


DT::datatable(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this - a mix of the DataTables API, jQuery and JavaScript:

```r
library(DT)

df = data.frame(
  category = c("A","B","C","D"),
  position = c(4,3,2,1)
)


datatable(df, options = list(
  initComplete = JS(
    "function(settings, json) {",
    "  var allNodes = this.api().table().rows().nodes().toArray();",
    "  var firstLast = [ allNodes[0], allNodes[allNodes.length -1] ];",
    "  $(firstLast).css({'background-color': 'red', 'color': 'white'});",
    "}")
))
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

---

But this depends on what exactly you mean by "first" and "last". With this approach (using `initComplete`), the formatting will move with the row data, when the rows are sorted/filtered by the user. So, what starts out as "first" and "last" may change.

---

References:

- [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)
- [`rows().nodes()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes())